# Stream audio using Pulseaudio server using ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, streaming

I have a desktop and a laptop running desktop ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to use my desktop to stream audio to my laptop. I installed paprefs on both machines. I also installed pavucontrol on both machines.

I was able to see the sound card installed in my desktop on my laptop's sound settings screen. Although I am unable to stream any audio.

I am confused on to where to look I've looked around in the interent and I just can't find the answer. Some stuff deals with the terminal which is fine, but it appears I should be able to do all of this thru the gui. I think I'm close, but just need a little more help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use vlc-mediaplayer:
Latest info should be worked by in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems
The info for using r(eal-time)t(ransport)c(ode)p(rotocol) is in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_Control_Protocol
Good-Luck
https://wiki.videolan.org/RTCP/